# How to pass log file in pg_dump

Tags: bash, postgresql, unix

I am using this command to export.

```
export PGPASSWOD=${PASSWORD}

    pg_dump –i –b -o -host=${HOST} -port=5444 -username=${USERNAME} -format=c -schema=${SCHEMA} --file=${SCHEMA}_${DATE}.dmp ${HOST}
```

Just want to know how can i include the log file in it so that i can get logs also.

Answer (score 18):

I assume you mean you want to capture any errors, notifications, etc that are output by pg_dump in a file.

There is no specific option for this, but pg_dump will write these to STDERR, so you can easily capture them like this:

```
pg_dump –i –b -o ...other options ... 2> mylogfile.log
```

In a shell, `2>` redirects STDERR to the given file.

This advice is good for nearly any command line tool you are likely to find on a *nix system.

Comment: If you want to append to the log file instead of overwrite it `pg_dump –i –b -o ...other options ... 2>> mylogfile.log`